# How to calculate difference between values coming from the same row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate the difference of values list coming from a database.
I would like to achieve it using php or mysql, but I do not know how to proceed.
I have a table named player_scores. One of its rows contains the goals scored.

Ex.

```
pl_date         pl_scores
03/11/2014      18
02/11/2014      15
01/11/2014      10
```

I would like to echo the difference between the goals scored during the matches played in different dates.

```
Ex:
pl_date       pl_scores    diff
03/11/2014     18          +3
02/11/2014     15          +5
01/11/2014     10          no diff
```

How can I obtain the desired result?

Comment: I think you mean the same table, not row

Comment: @AdamHopkinson, +1 for thinking right but sometimes you can have different values in the same $row. and if that is the case then OP, you need to separate your values by something like , or | or {} and then get the values in your PHP page and it would be easier to calculate the difference.

Comment: Can you? The question pretty clearly shows a table with one score per row

Comment: yes, you can have multiple values in the same row. but I understand what you stated and thats why i gave you a plus 1 ;)

Comment: @Flosculus, have you heard of concat ?

Comment: Thats only possible from the application's point of view.  A "column" conceptually containing multiple values still only contains a single value.  Further more Adam is right, he meant table because the data clearly shows a list of multiple results which need to be compared.

Comment: @Flosculus, yes, that is correct. but you can still use explode(); function and separate the string where you need them to be separated and then do whatever you want with each separated value.

Comment: Strictly speaking there is the MySQL function FIND_IN_SET to find a value in a comma separated list of values in a column, and there are also other wise to access delimited values (cross join against a series of integers, then use the integer with SUBSTRING_INDEX to access each value), but the need for these tends to suggest a badly designed database.

Comment: i don't think there is a "bad designed" database if the database works fine for what you're trying to do with it! the only time that you could say the database is designed badly is when it doesn't work or throws errors. example, I've created a simple 2 way chat that stores all the messages in one column/row. this works fine because each chat table will be deleted after 4 hours but I'm sure it won't be able to handle a large amount of data (messages) in one column and thats when you can call it a badly designed database....

Comment: Having multiple delimited values in a single field means that any check for one of those values cannot use an index and performance will be poor, throwing away most of the advantages of a database. Further if you are storing integer id fields in there they are being stored as characters (which take more space). Better to split them into another table with a 1 to many relationship. Worse is trying to get a value out of a php serialised array stored in a text field! There are occasions a limited field is fine, but there are many questions on here from people who are suffering from their misuse.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to compare a score against the score on a previous row.

Possibly simplest if done using a a sub query that gets the max pl_date that is less than the pl_date for the current row, then joining the results of that sub query back against the player_scores table to get the details for each date:-

```
SELECT ps1.pl_date, ps1.pl_scores, IF(ps2.pl_date IS NULL OR ps1.pl_scores = ps1.pl_scores, 'no diff', ps1.pl_scores - ps1.pl_scores) AS diff
FROM
(
    SELECT ps1.pl_date, MAX(ps2.pl_date) prev_date
    FROM player_scores ps1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN player_scores ps2
    ON ps1.pl_date > ps2.pl_date
    GROUP BY ps1.pl_date
) sub0
INNER JOIN player_scores ps1
ON sub0.pl_date = ps1.pl_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN player_scores ps2
ON sub0.prev_date = ps2.pl_date
```

There are potentially other ways to do this (for example, using variables to work through the results of an ordered sub query, comparing each row with the value stored in the variable for the previous row)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
 coalesce(
 (SELECT concat(IF(t1.pl_scores>t2.pl_scores,'+',''),(t1.pl_scores-t2.pl_scores))
     FROM tableX t2 WHERE t2.pl_date<t1.pl_date ORDER BY t2.pl_date DESC LIMIT 1)
 , 'no data' ) as diff
FROM tableX t1
WHERE 1
order by t1.pl_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two queries, one to get the value to use in the comparison (in the example below is the smaller number of scores) and the second one to get the records with a dedicated column with the difference:

```
SELECT MIN(pl_scores);

SELECT pl_date, pl_scores, (pl_scores - minScore) as diff FROM player_scores;
```

Or, using a transaction (one query execution php side):

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT MIN(Importo) FROM Transazione INTO @min;

SELECT Importo, (Importo - @min) as diff FROM Transazione;
```

Comment: Hi Gino,
Your query works properly, but I cannot extract the diff with php.
I used this loop to echo the diff rsults:    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT pl_scored_goal, (pl_scored_goal - @min) as diff FROM hb_games");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo $row['diff'];
}

Comment: try $row->diff to access the diff.

Comment: Hi Gino, I also tried to echo the result using $row->diff, but it does not work.

Comment: Hi, I printed sql using print_r and I got this: Resource id #9

Comment: I also printed diff using var_dump() and I got NULL NULL
 instead of 4 and -9

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT score FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = TheDateYouWant 

$score = $data['score']; 

 SELECT score FROM TABLE WHERE date = dateYouWant
 $difference = $score - $data['score'];
```

Something like this?